# How to build my own view for apache solr module

Tags: php, drupal, solr

After successful integration of apache solr module in drupal 7 and displaying the result Ii found that it is using the view files (search-results.tpl.php & search-result.tpl.php) from the core search module to display the result.

How can I use my custom files similar to (search-results.tpl.php & search-result.tpl.php) inside the apache solr module folder to display the result?

Since I am new to drupal and just started can somebody guide me to implement it.

Comment: I'm closing this to point at the duplicate question asked at Drupal.SE: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44253/how-to-build-my-own-view-for-apache-solr-module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .tpl.php files are theme template files, and you can override them by using identically named files in your own theme. Some deeper reading at [Drupal docs](http://drupal.org/node/173880).

Or you could use the search features provided by Google, as I did, and find [an already existing answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/4614/5678) on a related site.